# Qt Designer make widget overlap another widget in layout

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I want to make 3 window button like above picture (similar Google Chrome) use Qt Designer and PyQt.

I want 3 buttons overlap right side of TabWidget. 
But I only can overlap the Button on TabWidget when break layout like the picture.

When I set any layout, every widget can not overlap on each other. 
So can I overlap when set layout? Thanks.

This is the layout I want

[image]

It similar Google Chrome's layout

[image]

Comment: The point of a layout is to position your widgets in a predefined, user-friendly way. Normally people don't overlap widgets. If you want to do that there are multiple options including painting the widget yourself on top of everything, excluding the widget you want to overlap the rest from the layout and position it manually etc.

Comment: Thank @rbaleksandar! Do you have any example. I am beginer in Qt.

Comment: The second suggestion I've made should be easy enough: just don't add your widget to the layout you have in place. Manually positioning a widget is done by using `QWidget::move(...)`. Painting the widget is more advanced so I would not recommend it. Anyway normally you don't manually position stuff since you need to consider a lot of additional factors (mainly events such as resizing) that the layout takes off of your hands. Think about redesigning your idea in a way that doesn't involve such actions.

Comment: Thank @rbaleksandar, I am done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done in creator/designer, and can only be achieved using [`setCornerWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#setCornerWidget) from your code.

Since only one widget can be set for each corner, you have to create a QWidget that acts as a container, then add the buttons to it.

[image: corner widget example]

```
class Test(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ...

        self.createButtons()

    def createButtons(self):
        # create the container and its layout
        self.buttonContainer = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        buttonLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.buttonContainer)

        # remove margins around the layout and set a minimal spacing between
        # the children widgets
        buttonLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        buttonLayout.setSpacing(1)

        # QToolButtons are usually better for this, as QPushButtons tend
        # to expand themselves
        self.minimizeButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(text='_')
        self.maximizeButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(text='o')
        self.closeButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(text='x')
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.minimizeButton)
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.maximizeButton)
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.closeButton)

        # set the container as the corner widget; as the docs explain,
        # despite using "TopRightCorner", only the horizontal element (right
        # in this case) will be used 
        self.tabWidget.setCornerWidget(
            self.buttonContainer, QtCore.Qt.TopRightCorner)
```

Comment: How can I minimize padding, margin of corner button to top right of tab widget? I want the button stick to top of form, so when I hover mouse to top right, I can click to 'X' button

Comment: @ĐứcHảiTrần According to my tests the buttons are already placed on the top right corner of the tab widget, but it's possible that in some systems the default button size hint is smaller than the tabbar. Try to set each button's minimumHeight to `self.tabWidget.tabBar().sizeHint().height()`. It's possible that this would make it overlap the tab bar base, if that's the case, subtract the result of `self.style().pixelMetric(QtWidgets.QStyle.PM_TabBarBaseHeight, None, None)` from the sizeHint height.

Comment: I want remove padding (red arrow in image link) [image](https://i.imgur.com/ydecX14.jpg). I already tried to set minimizeHeight but there are no effect.

Comment: Those are the *drawing* margins of the buttons, and they completely depend on the style. In fact, even if the mouse is not exactly within the visual border of the buttons, you can still click on them and they will react accordingly. While you could manually move a widget by taking those margins into account, there's practically no way to know the size of that *visual* padding, because the drawing is done using internal computations, and pixmaps are often used. Even if you find a way to do that by trial and error, there is no guarantee that it will look the same on other computers.

Comment: The only alternative is to `setStyleSheet()` for each button (including all possible pseudo-states) with different border styles (usually `inset` and `outset`), or paint them by yourself by subclassing QPushButton (or QToolButton) and overriding their `paintEvent` methods, but that will obviously break visual consistency with the system.